# COUNT and SEARCH in REDIS hashes HMSET

Tags: search, count, redis, hash

REDIS experts please help. I want to count and search in redis hashes.

My user data:

```
| id | name    | age | country |
| 1  | jaspal  | 32  | US
| 2  | singh   | 45  | UK
| 4  | manjot  | 24  | US
| 5  | tarleen | 20  | UK
| 7  | daljeet | 30  | US
| 8  | sutdhar | 40  | US
```

... and so on

I stored this user data in redis using HMSET like:

```
HMSET user:1 name "jaspal"  age "32" country "US"
HMSET user:2 name "singh"   age "45" country "UK"
HMSET user:4 name "manjot"  age "24" country "US"
HMSET user:5 name "tarleen" age "20" country "UK"
HMSET user:7 name "daljeet" age "30" country "US"
HMSET user:8 name "sutdhar" age "40" country "US"
```

Now I want the following:

1. Count no of records in hash user.
2. Get records only `WHERE country=US AND age BETWEEN 31 AND 40`.

Comment: an idea: for each country create a separate ordered set (zset). in the set, names are the members and ages are the scores. this way you will be able to query by age and to find a specific country.

Answer (score 3):

You cant do that only with hashes. Redis does not support search by value; In your case you need to use [sorted sets](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set) to store age and country in score and user id in value. For example:

```
zadd user:ages 30 1 34 2 45 3 and so on...
```

Than you can select all users with are in specified age range:

```
zrangebyscore user:ages 30 40
```

and the same for countries (you need to use numeric countries representation)

You can use lua script to intersect or union select results on redis side

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of records in hash user use [HLEN](http://redis.io/commands/HLEN). It returns the number of fields contained in the hash stored at key.

`HLEN user:1`

It will return '3'.